# Can't ping devices by IP address for devices allocated IPs by DHCP

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, router, dns, domain

I have a home network with a Trendnet wireless router and a Windows Domain. The Domain Controller/DNS server is a Windows 2000 Server and is configured to forward queries to DNS servers provided by the ISP. The router provides DHCP and is configured with the Windows 2000 Server as the DNS server.

The network has been set up for a couple of years and usually works fine.

When I connect iPhones to the network over WiFi, the router can ping the iPhones through its browser based admin interface, but Windows machines that are part of the Windows Domain cannot. A laptop was connected to the network over WiFi that wasn't joined to the domain and it *could* see the iPhones. The router UI shows that the laptop has a reserved IP allocated via DHCP.

All machines either have a static or DHCP allocated IP on the 192.168.0.* subnet.

```
Router                    - 192.168.0.1   - Static        - Wired
Windows Domain Controller - 192.168.0.8   - Static        - Virtual
Windows 7 Workstation     - 192.168.0.200 - DHCP Auto     - Wired
VMWare ESXi Host          - 192.168.0.201 - Static?       - Wired
iPhone 1                  - 192.168.0.202 - DHCP Auto     - WiFi
iPhone 2                  - 192.168.0.203 - DHCP Auto     - WiFi
Windows Vista Laptop      - 192.168.0.204 - DHCP Reserved - WiFi
```

Using the Windows 7 machine (200), I try to ping each machine and the only DHCP machine that responds is itself. The other DHCP machines fail with `Reply from 192.168.0.200: Destination host unreachable.`. Using `nslookup` fails with `*** domain.controller.name can't find 192.168.0.203: Non-existent domain`.

Using the Windows 2000 Domain Controller (8), I try to ping each machine and the only DHCP machine that responds is the Windows 7 machine (200). Pinging the other DHCP machines fails with `Request timed out.`. Using `nslookup` also fails with `*** domain.controller.name can't find 192.168.0.203: Non-existent domain`.

Using the iPhone 2 (203), I try to ping (Network Ping Lite) the machines with static IP addresses and that works fine. When I try to ping the Windows 7 machine (200) it is unable to get a response.

How do I configure the DNS server/Windows Domain/Router properly so that the Windows Domain machines can see the IPs allocated via DHCP?

Comment: A bit of further snooping reveals that any DHCP allocated IP machine (including Windows workstations) can't be resolved with nslookup. My Windows 7 workstation does have an entry in the forward lookup zone, but not the reverse lookup zone. The iPhones have an entry in neither.

Comment: Are you pinging by ip or name?

Comment: Pinging by IP address.

Comment: you cant ping it, but can you work with device? ping can be disabled on eyephone.

Comment: I *can't* ping the iPhones by IP address or name from any Windows machine that is part of the domain. I *can* ping it by IP address from the router, and from a Windows Vista laptop that is *not* joined to the domain.

Comment: There's no reason why being in an Active Directory domain should affect your ability to ping other machines.  Double-check the network settings.  Is there any other difference between these machines and the laptop - for example, are these machines on a wired network?

Comment: The Vista laptop and the iPhones are connected over WiFi. The machines joined to the domain are connected physically or are a virtual machine.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I've listed the network settings.

Comment: Perhaps the router is implementing a firewall between the wireless and wired parts of the network?

Comment: Or, perhaps it thinks the wired and wireless parts of the network are supposed to be in different subnets.

Comment: I'll try a different router with it. I've ordered an [Asus RT-N56U](http://www.asus.com/Networks/Wireless_Routers/RTN56U/). I'll see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced my existing router with a new Asus RT-N56U wireless router. My computers can now see the iPhones.

Comment: Had to restart mine.